# Entity Framework 6.0 not auto-generating 'On Changing' or 'On Change' partial methods for table fields

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am generating entity framework classes from a SQL Server table. However I am not seeing the partial methods like the example below:

```
partial void OnFirstNameChanging(global::System.String value);
partial void OnFirstNameChanged();
```

I am using VS2012 & EF6.0. Many online examples talks about over-ridding these partial methods in newly created partial classes to put validation logic. But I can't find these methods in my auto-generated code. Is this something that's manually added in EF6.0? Will appreciate feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong generator. Those methods are only generated by `EntityObject` based generator (the one which is deprecated). Default generator uses POCO classes where these partial methods are not generated - you can modify the generator to add them (it is a T4 template).

To use `EntityObject` generator:

- Delete current .tt file stacked under your EDMX.
- Open EDMX, right click in the designer and select *Add code generation item* from context menu.
- If you don't see *EF 6.x EntityObject Generator* in *Visual C# Items* select *Online* and search for this generator.
- Install the generator and use it.
- Now your generated entities should support those partial methods.

Opening .tt file and searching for *Changing* and *Changed* words will give you and idea what is necessary to do in case of adding those methods to POCO generator.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If the functionality is deprecated then I'll follow the new recommend method. Can you please point to any example on how I can add custom logic to validate each property. Previously it was done by overriding e.g. OnFirstNameChanged method. I am already using data annotations for basic validation. Thanks again!