# OnPropertyChange equivalent for Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I am trying to figure out how to elegantly add logic to Entity Framework 6 POCOs, something like OnPropertyChanging and OnPropertyChanged in this solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716747(v=vs.100).aspx

Problem is, it seems like it has been deprecated...

[Entity Framework 6.0 not auto-generating 'On Changing' or 'On Change' partial methods for table fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862050/entity-framework-6-0-not-auto-generating-on-changing-or-on-change-partial-me)

Does anyone know the recommended way to add logic to and entity framework 6 model? Looking for something that is easy to maintain and won't get overwritten when I generate the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the answer to your second link?

Comment: I went down that road but it breaks scaffolding. Technically it is a solution, but I might as well downgrade to EF 5 or earlier. Argh.

Comment: If you really want your entities to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged\Changing` you have to modify the t4 template. But it is deprecated for a reason. INPC in entity classes quickly turns into spaghetti, I'd really seriously reconsider using it. It may be appropriate in view models, in entities I think it's hell.

Comment: I agree...A little more clear to me now, but I still can't figure out what the intended replacement was. Any ideas? The "Recommended" way to add logic to the model.

Comment: I'm doing an upgrade for a customer and they just want EF4 to EF6 as quickly and simply as possible. It's really frustrating because there are so many damned breaking changes between the two. These people are using OnPropertyChanged, AssociationChanged, AcceptAllChanges, entityCollection.Load, entity.Delete, and the list goes on. What a major PITA this is. I wish they put out a document with a simple upgrade path for each. If you know of a document like that, please let me know. Otherwise, I guess I'll have to write one. There goes my weekend.